# Zero vectors and additive inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $V = R$ is the set of all real number and $F = R$ is the field of scalars. Define operations of addition $\oplus$ and scalar multiplication $\circ$ as follows

$$x \oplus y = x + y + 1$$
$$ x\circ y = \alpha x + \alpha + 1$$
$$x,y \in R, \alpha \in R$$
Now its easy to prove these are closed for addition and scalar multiplication since $x,y \in R$ and all $\alpha \in R$ So since everything is in $R$ it must be closed
$$$$

I need to show that

'There exists a vector $0 \in V$ such that $v + 0 = v$ for all $v \in R$"

However when I try this
$$ 0 \in V, \therefore 0 \in R$$
$$ 0 \oplus x = x + 1$$
or
$$ 0 \oplus y = y + 1$$

which $\neq 0$
$$$$

For additive inverse 
'There exists a vector $-v \in V$ such that $v + (-v) = 0$'

$$ a = -y$$
$$ a \oplus y = -y \oplus y = y -y +1 = 1$$
$$$$

yet I am supposed to prove both these are possible as there exist a $v$ and $-v$ respectively
$$$$

So what am I missing?

Comment: May be the real number $0$ is not the zero element $0_V$ of $V$? Have you tried to find some other number that would work better? The requirement is $0_V\oplus x=x$ for all $x$. Try and solve for $0_V$!

Comment: Was $x\circ y$ meant to read $\alpha\circ x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zero vector is $-1$. Indeed

$$ x\oplus (-1) =x-1+1=x $$

while the inverse of $x$ is $$y=-x-2.$$ Indeed

$$x\oplus(-x-2)=x-x-2+1=-1$$ which is your zero vector

Answer (score 1):

If $x+y+1=x$ then $y+1=0$ so $y=-1$. Sure enough this proves to be the zero element.